# IndexIng 2d array with 2d matrix specified row and column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 6×6 matrix A, i'm trying to indexing the matrix A using two 2×2 matrices B and C. Each row of B and C specify a pair of indices for row and column in A. In detail, each row of B will specify the row needed to be indexed and each row of C specify the column.
For example,

```
A = np.arange(0,36).reshape(6,6)
B = np.array([[0,1],
        [2,4]])
C = np.array([[1,2],
        [3,4]])
```

I need to get a 2×2×2 matrix like this:

```
results = 
[[[ 1  2]
  [7  8]]

 [[15 16]
  [27 28]]]
```

[example of indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIaQb.png)

If just get one matrix using index like B=[0,1] and C=[1,2],  it can be done with:

```
d = A[B,:]
results = d[:,C]
```

But things different when I need to get two 2×2 matrices (2×2×2)， and each matrix is index using each row of B and C.

p.s. Please change the title of this question if you can think of a more precise one.

Comment: A is a multi-dimensional (2D) array. for accessing elements in array A, you must give 2 indices. A[0] != 1, A[0] is a array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]). that is the reason it outputs you arrays instead of values.

Comment: I'm a little confused, so how can i get the  2×2×2 matrix using indeces of B and C?

Comment: can you change the problem to one of getting a (2,3,4) array?.  Keeping track of dimensions will be easier.

Comment: Acturally, the resulting matrix is not resrict to (2,2,2). For (n1,n2) B and (n1,n3) C, matrix B will indicate the row indices and matrix C will indicate the column indices, the results will be (n1,n2,n3). Notice, A must a 2d array, and the first dimension of B and C must be the same.